# Just got my first ever initial job offer, negotiate or not?

Tags: software-industry, negotiation

First, a little about me. I graduated last year with a Software Engineering degree, but have had no luck in getting a full job offer, until now. I had no internships and a pretty average GPA. I'm working on a side project, but other than that, all of my projects were done in school.

So, I live in a relatively low CoL area, and I just got a job offer for 60k in Atlanta, Georgia. The offer includes bi-anual performance based merit reviews, with each review promising a potential raise. It also includes all the standard health, dental, vision insurance, 401k, stock, etc etc. I also get a relocation stipend to help with the move. Remote work is expected to go on for a few more months.

In my opinion I'm in no position to negotiate as I have no prior experience and I consider myself a pretty average entry level developer, and the promise of bi anual raises sound nice, but that only matters if I like working at the company for that amount of time.

If you were in my shoes, what would you do? Take the job to get much needed experience in the field? I just feel like it's unnecessary risk asking for a 5-10k raise?

Any advice would be great, thank you!

Comment: No one here can make that kind of decision for you. If you're happy with the offer then take it. -- But some advice. Be careful what you share online. This question shares so much unnecessary detail. Your location, your age, graduation date etc...

Comment: Thanks for advice, I edited it.

Comment: “I just feel like it's unnecessary risk asking for a 5-10k raise?” You should decide to negotiate after you plan out a budget.  60K isn’t a great deal in Atlanta Georgia; I just recall that 60K wasn’t a great deal, and I lived an hour outside of Atlanta, and money was extremely tight

Comment: I already had, and my expenses are low, even for the area I'd be living in, since I have no dependents and I really don't go out much. I just feel like even if I asked if negotiation is possible it could be a risk, and I've been trying far too long to finally get my foot in the door at a pretty reputable company.

Comment: I would also be pretty surprised if a first attempt to negotiate would result in the initial offer being retracted.

Comment: @TheyCallMeDK your instinct is correct.  Negotiating salary on a *first software job* would just be seen as naive / a bit silly.  Everyone knows First Software Jobs  have crap pay, and 5k is not even worth worrying about.  As I explain in a Detailed Answer™.  Good luck!

Comment: You need to ask yourself "Based on what would you ask for 5-10K more?" Market for entry level in that city? Just because you think "Whatever they offer, ask for 5K more?" How much you need to support the lifestyle you have/want is irrelevant.

Answer (score 18):

**I would take the job as is.**

Software development is a field which accepts short job tenures. I had a new offer within 6 months of my first job, had a bunch of others after, and left it 51 weeks later. [60,000 is bang on what junior developers are getting in Atlanta anyway.](https://www.glassdoor.ca/Salaries/atlanta-junior-software-developer-salary-SRCH_IL.0,7_IM52_KO8,33.htm) Take the offer, as getting a job is a heck of a lot easier if you even have 6 months of experience compared to 0. I have one year of experience now and recruiters have reached the point of being a burden to deal with every week. It took me 4 months to find the first job. I was plucked by a former co-worker for my current one. I think it would take me 4-6 weeks to find my third.

I wouldn't negotiate, especially since it took a year to get this far. Take the job, lock it down, gain your footing in the industry, and plan to look at new opportunities in a year. Focus not on whether this job is 60-65K but how soon you can get the next job of 80K.

Answer (score 6):

> In my opinion I'm in no position to negotiate as I have no prior experience and I consider myself a pretty average entry level developer

I'd go with your gut feeling and see how it works out. You can always leave if it doesn't, but a reasonable offer should be met at face value unless you have other solid options. Negotiation is always a risk, and it's better to get the experience while you have few expenses rather than go for broke, time enough to do that when you have experience and a more expensive lifestyle to support.

For a first job the most important thing to consider is whether it will cover your bills and hobbies with a bit of a cushion left over to impress the ladies with.

Comment: I'm a pretty cheap spender, it's something my family always bugged me about. As long as I can get a decent gaming PC and Netflix subscriptions that's all I need, really. I looked at the rent in the region and it would be under 30% my monthly take home, leaving a lot for saving.

Comment: Well, that's my advice for you. No need to be hard-nosed at this stage in your career, the most important thing is to start building experience asap. If you imagine 30% then it will be more like 60%. Because hopefully you will get some nice stuff for your family and you'll be surprised how money just seems to spend itself the more independent you get. You've already sat out a year unemployed.

Answer (score 2):

There are no hard and fast rules to negotiating.

It sounds like you think this is a pretty good offer considering you don't have any real world experience. IMO, $60K is a pretty good starting salary for any IT related job. What is the market value in Atlanta for a person like you? Is it comparable to your offer? Is your offer below, at, or above the average/median salary?

I'm inclined to agree with your assessment that this offer is pretty good for a person in your position, and if it were me, I probably wouldn't attempt to negotiate a higher salary.

Answer (score 1):

## The "first job" rules in software...

In the software industry,

1. It's hard to "break in" and get that first job. It's not unlike trying to get a start in the music or acting business.
2. First jobs pay badly.
3. Don't wait more than about a year to move along from your first job.
4. You rarely get away from "first job pay" other than by moving along to a new company (and, see point 3).

All that you mention is just "rule 2" - so, you're in good shape so far.

I wouldn't even bother about the 5k difference you mention. In a couple years, all goes well you'll be making so much more money that what you made back in the day won't be relevant.

Regarding the fact **that Atlanta is expensive**.  You unfortunately just have to suck it up.  (See points 1, 2, 3, 4.)  In as little as a couple years, you'll be able to live anywhere you want, eat at *Revival* every night, or, just take a full remote job if you happen to prefer that.

It looks great on your resume having worked (on site) in a major market.  Enjoy!

## Key tips...

1. I truly URGE you to get a flat or share **literally within doors** of the office. You DON'T want to waste one second of your life, when you are working in a field as intense as software. Walking distance only from your digs to the office.
2. You know how you mention an extra 5 or 10k.  Don't forget as a programmer the easiest thing in the world is to *do the odd freelance job* to bring in a few grand here and there. So don't even worry about money.  (Conversely, generally it's *not* possible to do side-jobs when programming, but, it's your first job and if you keep it low-key, and don't waste 5 hours a week on commuting, you're good.)

Answer (score 0):

You can start by asking if this offer is negotiable. Sometimes they will say no, and you won't try. Sometimes they will ask what you have in mind, in which case you'll be prepared to ask for something.

Right now, do some market research about typical compensation. If you find your salary fits the market you should not feel obligated to try. You can instead ask for something small and targeted, like a larger relocation bonus, a sign-on bonus, or RSUs. If you feel the market suggests a higher salary, and they do not shut down negotiation entirely, then show your numbers and politely ask for something higher. Be willing to settle for a counter offer.

Answer (score -2):

This is an initial offer, anchored at 60k. Not counter-offering will leave them believing their initial offer was too high. How this will effect future raises as well as their expectations...?

[Education for negotiations](https://hbswk.hbs.edu/archive/when-to-make-the-first-offer-in-negotiations)

- Who has your best interests at heart?
- Negotiating is a skill, learn it now.
- Positions have bands, not a set value.
- What has you own research shown?
- They offered you a position because they **want** *you*!

Obviously, if your research shows a band of 50k-70k in your area, don't counter with 100k. And use soft, not hard tactics. e.g. "I'm worth way more than that" would not be productive.

Comment: Any serious company will usually have already a good knowledge of where their salary stands in the market. It seems they don't try to lowball, so if the offer seems fair, I see no reason of negotiating. Also on which basis would you be negotiating? What do you have to bring? Bluffing is not a good option in this case I'm afraid, you might just look greedy.

Comment: @LaurentS. Basic negotiating 101. Ignore at your own risk.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer because I think it's a valid answer despite me not agreeing. I'm probably being naive on that, but I pretty much would love that the salary discussions are more open and fair play. As I can't force others to be more reasonable, I can at least try to be reasonable myself, and hopefully lead by example. Starting a work relationship negotiating a proposed amount I already defined as acceptable for me just doesn't seem like the ideal solution for me. I don't see any more risks with one option or the other.

Comment: I think an important thing to consider here is that it is OP's first work experience. I can probably relate to your answer more in the case of a somewhat experienced profile, where you have more room for discussing your added value and previous accomplishments, which are not just getting some grades from some school